# How to convert POJO class list to Object list?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I have a pojo class name User. Now I am creating ArrayList of User's class using following statement.

```
ArrayList<User> userArrayList = new ArrayList();
```

I have another class whose constructure accept a arraylist of Object i.e.

```
 public className(ArrayList<Object> objectArrayList){
 }
```

Now if I want to pass userArrayList into objectArrayList then what conversion should I need to use

Comment: Why would you want to turn it into an object? Seems to me, either use generics or redesign your API.

Comment: Im not sure exactly what you are asking, but everything inherits from `Object`, so no conversion is necessary to pass it. To do things inside your function conversion is necessary.

Comment: @HypnicJerk, I know every class in Java is inherits from base Object, class but then also it is giving me an error.

Comment: @ifly6 , yes I am creating a kind of generic class for a component called RecylcerView's adapter in Android.

Comment: chagne your second class declaration to `public className(ArrayList<?> objectArrayList){
 }`

Comment: @Sotirios ,Thank you for duplicate links, my problem is solved now :)